# SCSS custom function and String extra quotes

Tags: css, sass

I've stacked with custom functions in SCSS/SASS.
There's code of custom function:

```
require 'sass'

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def s3_path(path)
    assert_type path, :String
    image_url("#{APP_CONFIG[:system][:s3_host]}/#{path.gsub(/^([\/]+)/, '')}".gsub(/(["]+)/, ''))
  end

  declare :reverse, :args => [:string]
end
```

There'se call in css:

```
ul li a span{
    background: s3_path('email_new/menu.png') no-repeat;
}
```

And there's output

```
.menu ul li a span {
    background: url('https://***DOMAIN***/"email_new/menu.png"') no-repeat;
}
```

But expected variant is

```
.menu ul li a span {
    background: url('https://***DOMAIN***/email_new/menu.png') no-repeat;
}
```

You can see extra quotes in the compiled css. So i've tried to `gsub` it with no luck.
Why does scss adds these quotes to a string? And how to remove them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`unquote`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) SASS method ?